# Switch site language after IP to locale redirect

Tags: i18n-l10n, redirection

I have a Multilingual Drupal 7 website. using [i18](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n). I redirect my visitors based on IP address with [IP to locale](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip2locale) module. Now e.g. visitors from Holland (Dutch IP) are redirected to http://landberg.at/nl

But now I am not able to select another language, with my [language switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_switcher)? E.g an English person who lives in Holland must be able to switch to the English version. http://landberg.at/en

How do I have to achieve this? Is this anyway possible with language redirect based on IP?

(currently on my site I switched IP 2 locale OFF)

Comment: Is this for D6 or D7? Consider editing your question to clarify that ...

Comment: A Drupal 7 website.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried [Language Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_switcher) module but you are not getting any result. Once try to use [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown') module.

> Language Switcher Dropdown is a very simple module that exposes a new
>   block, similar to the default Language Switcher block provided by
>   Locale module. The new block allows site visitors to switch languages
>   using a drop-down select list instead of using hyperlinks.

Comment: i just tested it but it doesn't make a difference. Still after redirect your not able to switch language. You can test it [here](http://landberg.at/).

Comment: I have just check, Default English is showing. When I click on German, it redirect to English but when I select Dutch it redirect to Nederland & page url is change to 'http://landberg.at/nl'. I think your language selection configuration inside `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection` is wrong. Please check.

Comment: Thanks i have now inside `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection: -URL -Standaard` But if i enable: `-URL -User -Standaard` I get in my browser an error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS –

Answer (score 0):

## Consider a special patch

Your issue seems fairly similar to what is described in [Patch for language switcher to override ip2locale](https://www.drupal.org/node/974392). It is for D6 though (not sure what this question is for D6 or D7 ... I think D7). Not sure if you want to consider exprimenting with the patch attached to it (attention: status of the issue is "needs review").

## Check language detection

It seems to me that you should check your configuration at Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection: the order specified there could be what explains the current behaviour in your site.

You'd have to experiment a bit with what the exact order in your case should be. In my experience, I often get these kind of issues to work by using an order like 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'. It could well be that that is all that's needed here ... So try to experiment a bit with the various combinations in this order to see if it helps.

Curious to hear what the result of checking this will be ...

Comment: Thanks i have now:
-URL 
-Standaard

But if i enable:
-URL
-User  
-Standaard

I get in my browser an error:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS